# Как использовать Window.document в Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Я хотел подключить свой фронт на js с бэком на Node js. Но, когда я запустил сервер, то Node.js выдал ошибку, т.к. в нем нет Window. Как мне использовать querySelector в Node.js?

Comment: Использовать querySelector для чего? Зачем он на бэке?

Comment: В Node.JS нет window. Что вы хотите реализовать на node.js? У меня есть подозрение, что вы не совсем представляете, для чего используется бэк и как им пользуется фронт.

Comment: @Swad, я хотел написать сервер на node.js и подключить туда свой фронт. Но, когда я импортировал нужные функции, то возникала ошибка, document is not defined. Да, я знаю, что node.js его не понимает. Мне нужно было решение, как изменять DOM элементы

Comment: Зачем изменять DOM элементы на бэке?

Comment: Бэк должен отдавать статику(html/js/css), а так же принимать и обрабатывать запросы от фронта или внешних источников. Какое понятие во фразу "подключить фронт к бэку" вы вкладываете. Да и работа с DOM должна вестить на стороне клиента. Сервер, правда, может по разным запросам отдавать разные HTML страницы и модифицировать исходный DOM на сервере с помощью шаблонов.

Comment: наверное ТС до этого на пхп писал и представляет, что сервер может "отдавать" код фронта. Действительно, я бы рекомендовал автору вопроса изучить вопрос что есть сервер, серверный язык, http запросы и остальную базу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В серверной среде Node.js нет объекта `window`, так как он предназначен для работы в браузерной среде.

Однако, если нужно работать с DOM-подобной структурой в Node.js, можно использовать библиотеки, такие как JSDOM или Cheerio.